# Photo Grid, image replacement swap instead of CSS background color

Tags: image, wordpress, hover, swap

I would like to use this theme http://demo.icypixels.com/themes/oneshot/
which nicely transform's each thumbnail to the desired color accompanied with the post type and portfolio name. But..

.. it would be perfect for my case if I could bring to front (on mouse over) an image (different for each thumbnail), instead of a color.

I have managed to accomplish a similar [effect](http://www.wpdummy.dreamhosters.com/gpagetryout01/) but it would be perfect if I could just hard-code that template or similar template / plugin.

Kinda confused there, but thanks in advance.

P.S. sorry for the English.

Comment: I've managed to add the image as background in the CSS and it looks promising, dunno if it is bad practice, any comments/advises are welcome. 
myTryout: http://bit.ly/XMqJOW

Answer (score 0):

Try this plug in search for it in Wordpress its called WP Visual Slide Box Builder. You can create custom shape boxes and add effect on hover. Its WYSIWYG so its pretty easy to use.